# Concatenating merged cells and on a specific condition in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this table where I want to concatenate each row in it on specific columns
[image: Table]

The concatenation should happen on columns `Option Name`,  `Type 1`, `Type 2`and `Existing measure`/`New measure`

For `Existing measure` and `New measure` wherever there is an entry that value should be picked up for concatenation.

The output I want is an array as below

```
[Name 1-C type 1-Yearly-GB, Name 1-C type 2-Monthly-MB, Name 2-C type 3-Quarterly-GB, Name 2-C type 2-Daily-Bytes,Name 2-C type 4-Monthly- MB,Name 3-C type 1-Yearly-KB]
```

I could use an array formula and concatenate and store in `column L` and read that column via apps script. but I want to use apps script to get the array I desire.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert your sample input Spreadsheet image to the array of `The output I want is an array as below`.
- You want to put the created array in the column "L".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("C7:K" + sheet.getLastRow());
  let temp = "";
  const ar = range.getDisplayValues().map(([c, , , , , ...v]) => {
    if (c) temp = c;
    return [[c, ...v].join("") && [temp, ...v.filter(String)].join("-")];
  });
  console.log(ar); // You can see the created array in the log.
  // If you want to retrieve the flattened array like your question, please use console.log(ar.flat());

  range.offset(0, 9, ar.length, 1).setValues(ar);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from columns "C" and "H" - "K", and an array is created including the string values concatenated columns "H" - "K". And, the created array is put to column "L".

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Although I did not want to put it in column L, just wanted to get the concatenated values in to the array.
Your script works like a charm and gives me what I need

Thank you so much Tanaike-san!